# Can I allow AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode for net.tcp WCF services?

Tags: c#, wcf

As in the title - i'm struggling to get my services to be hosted outside of basicHttp bindings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. Once you use AspNetCompatibility you degrade WCF service to .asmx service and you have all its limitations - including tight coupling with HTTP protocol because ASP.NET pipeline works only for HTTP(S) protocol.

Comment: ok - that's what i thought. i can't think where it thinks the service is using any asp.net features.. how can i remove all references to anything that might be doing this? I've removed all the system.web references from the service...

Comment: If you don't use `AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute` you should be fine. Also make sure that you don't use `WebServiceHost` instead of `ServiceHost`